# Need to parse a string in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

Part of my project is to retrieve a string variable from an external source (google docs) and parse it. This string represents width and height.
I have no problem retrieving, I just need to parse it in to two strings.
The string has 4 variations.
Here are examples:

```
3"x4"
3"hx4"w
3hx4w
3x4
```

The width is always the first number and the height is always the second. Sometimes, the width and height have decimal points.

I'm a regex nube. If anyone can help me parse this into two strings of the numeric values only, I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim matches = Regex.Matches("3.45x4.3""", "[\d.]+")

Console.WriteLine("width: " + matches(0).Value)
Console.WriteLine("height: " + matches(1).Value)
```

An English representation of the regex is basically `[\d.]` is a character that is either a digit or a dot. The `+` means one or more.

Comment: For the vb folk, here's the code in vb: Dim matches = Regex.Matches("3.45x4.3""", "[\d.]+")

Console.WriteLine("width: " + matches(0).Value)
Console.WriteLine("height: " + matches(1).Value)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you learn to fish as it will pay off dividends, and this is an extremely simple string to parse with regex.

*Edit*: It is even simpler than I thought.  You don't have to use most of the stuff I mentioned here, as you won't have to wade through multiple of these measurements on the same line.  [Check out Yuriy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8422091/232593).  Still, check out the rest of this and start learning some regex :)

You'll have to use grouping/captures to grab the data out that you've matched.  Wrap what you are trying to match with parens to do this:

```
(someTextToMatch)
```

Don't group things you don't need to capture, or use non-capturing groups for those:

```
(?:someTextToMatch)
```

(you probably won't need these for this example, but you may need them eventually as you only get 9 captures)

Immediately useful language elements:

```
\s     match any single whitespace character
\d     match any single digit
.      match any single character
[Xx]   match a single upper-case or lower-case x
?      match one or zero of the previous match
+      match one or more of the previous match
*      match zero or more of the previous match (probably won't need this here)
```

Some docs:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.71).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.71).aspx

I also recommend googling for regular expression tutorials.  Here's one that is .Net specific:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like the following would be the quick way of doing it

```
Dim s as string = GetStrinFromDocs()

' remove quotes
s.replace("""","")

'remove other chars
s.replace("w","")
s.replace("h","")

dim Width as integer = ctype(s.split("x")(0),integer)
dim Height as integer = ctype(s.split("x")(1),integer)
```

You should consider using regular expressions to do this too,

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html